# Can a nodeJs script delete his own file?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm working on an updater and I wish there is some way for the updater to update itself (remove and copy the new file from which the script is run).

- Is it possible?
- Is it a good practice?
- Have you got an advice for such a situation?

Comment: There's certainly nothing stopping you from deleting the source file, once it has been  required in a module it wont be read from disk again (unless you invalidate the cache, but that is a hack). Is it bad practice? In general, probably, but it sounds reasonable for your use case.

Comment: Self updating modules, especially those in the context of a package manager like npm, rub me the wrong way because they violate predictable state.  If I install `foo@1.0.1`, I want it be that and **always** be that until I purposefully install the next version.

Comment: @zero298 this is not a self updating module, but just a command to update the main application. However thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is it possible ? **Yes...**
- Is it a good practice ? **It depends, if you are updating an application, it could be a good approach...**
- Have you got an advice for such a situation ? **Not actually because if you need a new version of your app you must update the files but I would suggest a parallel app who is in charge of updating the main app...**

Example:

```
var fs  = require('fs');

console.log("I'm about to delete myself...");

console.log('clonning myself...');
fs.copyFileSync('./selfDelete.js', './selfDelete_bkp.js');

console.log('removing myself...');
fs.unlinkSync('./selfDelete.js');

console.log('new version of me...');
fs.renameSync('./selfDelete_bkp.js', './selfDelete.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a good practice.

And you cannot update while you running. 
What I can suggest is you can create a new file somewhere with updates and then replace the current file with the new file from a scheduled task which runs sometime later.
Not sure that answered your question but this is what I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the effort but can you provide more explanations on why it s a bad practice ? I don't have access to system files or cannot be sudo thus making a scheduled task is impossible for me actually. Thanks :)

Comment: If you working on a app which let user create their own js files an some environment and let them run instantly, then you might not have much of a choice. 
Otherwise I would suggest to use a DB for manage the app customisations else the changes could crash your app. I might be wrong by the way :)